# Reading from a text file and adding multiple firewall rules

Tags: powershell

I created a script that adds a new firewall rule, only if there isn't one already created. It checks the firewall rule name, along with the direction of the traffic. If the same firewall rule name exists, along with either an inbound or outbound connection, it will not create the rule. It reads from a text file on the local machine.

What I am trying to accomplish is to add multiple firewall rules in this script by reading a text file with multiple server names in it.

For example, I am trying to add 4 different firewall rules (2 inbound and 2 outbound) to a single server but I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Firewall rule names

- k1 (TCP- In)
- k2 (TCP- Out)
- k3 (TCP- In)
- k4 (TCP- Out)

Code:

```
$Computers = get-Content -Path "C:\temp\kofaxcomputers.txt"            
Write-host "Checking firewall rules now...." -ForegroundColor Cyan

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers {
    $firewallRuleName = "k1 (TCP- In)"

    if (Get-NetFirewallRule | ? {$_.DisplayName -eq $firewallRuleName -and ($_.Direction -eq 'Inbound' -or $_.Direction -eq 'Outbound')}) {
        Write-host "Firewall rule for '$firewallRuleName' already exists, not creating new rule" -ForegroundColor red
    }
    else {
        Write-host "Firewall rule for '$firewallRuleName' does not already exist, creating new rule now..."
        New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $firewallRuleName -Direction Inbound -RemoteAddress Any -Action Allow -Protocol TCP -LocalPort 2424

        Write-host "Firewall rule for '$firewallRuleName' created successfully" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a CSV that contains the Rules you want, you can use `Import-Csv` and a `foreach` loop to create the rules contained in the csv.

Example `kofaxrules.csv` contents:

```
"Name", "Direction", "Port"
"k1 (TCP- In)", "Inbound", "2424"
"k2 (TCP- Out)", "Outbound", "1212"
"k3 (TCP- In)", "Inbound", "3434"
"k4 (TCP- Out)", "Outbound", "6565"
```

Code:

```
$Computers = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\kofaxcomputers.txt"
$Rules = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\kofaxrules.csv"

Write-Host "Checking firewall rules now...." -ForegroundColor Cyan

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers -ScriptBlock {
    foreach ($Rule in $Using:Rules) {
        if (Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $Rule.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
            Write-Host "Firewall rule already exists $($Rule.Name)" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Creating Firewall rule: $($Rule.Name)"
            New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $Rule.Name -Direction $Rule.Direction -RemoteAddress Any -Action Allow -Protocol TCP -LocalPort $Rule.Port
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not been able to test as I'm on an Android device at present, but it should be very close if it's not correct first time :)

Comment: Thanks James, however when I try to run the script, I get the "Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters".      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-NetFirewallRule], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Get-NetFirewallRule

Comment: Updated - `Get-NetFirewallRule` didn't like both DisplayName and Direction.